# How to switch dataset in power bi desktop and power bi service?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have built a report after connecting to a live dataset.

Due to some reason I need to connect to a different model (which is same as the current model plus some new fields) because the current model is being decommissioned.

What is the way to change the model (live connection) in:

1. Power BI Desktop
2. Power BI Service

Answer (score 1):

In Desktop change this in Options and Settings / Data source settings

[image]

For a report in the service, download it as a PBIX, and change it in Desktop, or call the [Reports - Rebind Report In Group API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/rebind-report-in-group)